# Downloading Podcast on iPhone iOS 5.0 No Longer Shows Date In Music App

Tags: iphone, itunes, ios, music, podcasts

Since I upgraded to iOS 5 when I download podcasts from iTunes on my phone the date the podcast is published is no longer downloaded.

See the below screenshot, notice how the last podcast has a published date of 11/3, that one I downloaded via iTunes on my computer.  The others I used the iTunes store on the iPhone to download directly to the phone.  Downloading directly from iTunes on the phone is nice, but then the phone holds all of the podcasts out of order.

Thoughts?

[image]

Comment: Or you could just download the Instacast app and never mess with syncing podcasts in iTunes. Instacast has some many great features. Like being able to download or stream the podcast. Auto download new shows when connected to WiFi. Pulls show notes from the RSS feed. Totally worth the couple bucks and has totally improved my podcast experience on my iPhone.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is a bug in the Music or iTunes app on iOS 5. Something doesn't seem to store the date properly on podcasts downloaded on the phone, they don't show up in the app and if you transfer them back to your computer, iTunes shows the date as Dec 31, 2000 or something nonsensical.

Podcasts I download in iTunes on my Mac and then sync to my iPhone show the date fine.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. Seems if you had any podcasts in iOS 4, upgrading to iOS 5 is not really painless. The way I fixed it is to untick "sync podcasts to this device", then click apply, then tick that box again and sync again.

This will also restore the podcast album artwork and time remaining bug.

Comment: No luck, tried your suggestion and nothing changed.  Went as far as erasing all content on the phone, setting it back up from iCloud and still no dates.